# How to decrease network data usage for JMeter load tests

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

Whether the each sample of jmeter will use or increase data usage?, Is there any solution available.

Comment: What do you mean by 'sample' ? What is the issue you are facing? What you have tried before? Please add proper details to your question to get an answer.

Comment: Samples are HTTP request in jmeter.
Am using 
1500 threads in jmeter and 
10 http request and ramp-up time is 10. i been using this for the entire day. now my data usage has been increased to 10GB.  So now how can i reduce my data usage for this jmeter test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as I understand, your problem is that while doing load tests whole day you have exceeded your network data limit and you want to know if there any ways to minimize the data usage.

- Well, you can definitely minimize the data usage. But that is only possible by removing the samplers/requests. 10 GB is a lot of data and it seems that you are also performing static content requests in your JMeter scripts. So, you can remove these requests to reduce data usage.

But before doing so, you should ask the question if this approach is fine for your scenario. Normally, if we want to mimic real-time scenario then we include static requests. But if our load tests are to identify issues in specific area only then we can exclude static content requests.

Please check below question for further thoughts on this topic [include static resources like images, css, js etc in tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8725634/include-static-resources-like-images-css-js-etc-in-tests)

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. One more question is. If i want to test 1,00,000 thread(users) what will be the system configuration like RAM, processor Speed, JVM heap size and etc.

Comment: You are welcome. For your second question regarding hardware configuration .. check this question.. http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/15178/for-heavy-jmeter-scripts-what-type-of-servers-should-we-use-to-run-them

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following:

- Real browsers download embedded resources like images, styles, scripts, etc. But they do it **only once**, on subsequent requests the resources are being returned from the browser's cache. Add [HTTP Cache Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager) to your test plan to replicate this behaviour in your JMeter test
- Focus solely on your application. If it uses content from 3rd-party websites - you don't need to include it into JMeter test as you don't have control of external websites content and won't be able to do anything if it becomes unavailable or will be loading slowly. So use "Embedded URLs must match" input of the [HTTP Request Defaults](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults) to limit JMeter's scope to your domain(s) only. See [Excluding Domains from the Load Test](https://docs.blazemeter.com/customer/portal/articles/1903905-excluding-domains-from-the-load-test) guide for more details.